# "classes.dex not found. Try to rebuild project" in Android Studio

Tags: intellij-idea, android-studio, android-sdk-tools

I'm unable to build Android project using Android Studio 0.1.3. Everything worked fine until latest SVN update of the project. This is strange, because no settings were changed (SDK, dependencies etc.). I also didn't update any tools. I keep getting the error:

`Android Packager: [trunk] File /home/matis/.AndroidStudioPreview/system/compile-server/apilot_f8e91252/android/intermediate_artifacts/trunk/classes.dex not found. Try to rebuild project`

There are no errors in source code, I can build and deploy it on a device without problems using Eclipse. I'm using SDK rev. 17 with SDK Tools rev. 22.

I tried to build source from earlier SVN revision, but the same thing happens.

Has anyone else experienced similar problem? How can I solve it?

---

**Update**

After some investigation I found out that *dx* tool doesn't get called at all (I modified its script so it would create some file if run), but *aapt* is called properly.

Comment: Did you try to rebuild the project? On the menu: Build -> Rebuild.

Comment: @free3dom Forgot to mention it in the question, but that was of course the first thing I tried.

Comment: @Matis How do you call dx tool(I modified its script so it would create some file if run) can you please show me how to modified script?

Comment: @um.anusorn I just added 'touch TEST' to the beginning of sdk/build-tools/VERSION/dx script.